# date-time string to boost::gregorian::date

Tags: c++, string, datetime

I have the following `std::string` '2010-08-10T23:59:00' and I need to convert it to a `boost::gregorian::date` object.

I know I should use `boost::date_time::date_input_facet`, but I just cannot seem to figure out how to do it.

Can someone please assist me as to how to do this conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

boost's posix_time module supports a direct conversion from that form (which unless I'm confused is the ISO time format?). Take a look at:

```
boost::posix_time::from_iso_string
```

You just need to strip the formatting marks first.

```
posix_time::time_from_string
```

may work for you as well.

You should them be able to convert the posix_time into gregorian.

Hope this helps.

Comment: from_iso_string requires YYYYMMDD format, not YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: @quant_dev been a while, but I think I covered that with "You'll need to strip the formatting masks first"